# What's equivalent of availableForFlowActions in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have an LWC that I would like to be invoked as a flow action.

Is there an equivalent of availableForFlowActions which allows aura components to be invoked as flow actions? I can't seem to find anything in the documentation.

Thanks!

Comment: I am also looking for the same. Flow screen component LWC will need to be added to a flow screen. Flow Action whereas can be outside a flows screen. For use cases like navigating to a URL, sending email, callout etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible at the moment.

For what its worth I posted this idea to hopefully get this feature in a future release: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000QN8AaUAL/enable-local-actions-in-flow-using-lightning-web-components